# Is there a way to set a range for an int? And when outside that range for a certain int, a different int increments by 1

Tags: java

Building a program that will have imperial weights (stones, pounds and ounces), and I need ranges for the pounds and ounces (ie ounces 0-15), once the ounces int goes above 15, then pounds will increment by 1, with the same happening to pounds so that stones increments by 1.

I am fairly new to Java so this is new to me and I've no idea how to get it started.

```
public class NewWeight {

    private int stones = 0;
    private int pounds = 0;
    private int ounces = 0;

    public NewWeight (int stones, int pounds, int ounces) {
        ...
```

Say when there is an input of 18 ounces, the output would be `1 pound and 2 ounces`, another example being 224 ounces so that the output would end up being `1 stone, 0 pounds, 0 ounces`

Comment: What all operations you want to do on NewWeight ? Do you have input as ounces only or any of the three units ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use 3 variables `ounces`, `pounds` and `stones` here. All these three represent one quantity - weight.

You can just store the weight in ounces and nothing else:

```
private int weightInOunces;
```

Then you can add methods such as `getPounds`, `getStones` and `getOunces`, which do maths on `weightInOunces`.

For example:

```
public int getPounds() {
    return weightInOunces % 224 / 16;
}

public int getOunces() {
    return weightInOunces % 16;
}

public int getStones() {
    return weightInOunces / 224;
}
```

Setters could be implemented like this:

```
public int setPounds(int pounds) {
    int stones = getStones();
    weightInOunces = stones * 244 + getOunces() + pounds * 16;
}

public int setOunces(int ounces) {
    int pounds = getPounds();
    weightInOunces = pounds * 16 + ounces;
}

public int setStones(int stones) {
    weightInOunces = stones * 244 + weightInOunces % 244;
}
```

The constructor could be implemented like this:

```
public Weight(int stones, int pounds, int ounces) {
    weightInOunces = stones * 224 + pounds * 16 + ounces;
}
```

To achieve the output, you can also add a `toString` method that outputs the weight in the format `x stones, x pounds, x ounces`.

Comment: How would the setters work then with those getters? ie `setPounds(int pounds) { //pounds is set to variable }`

Comment: @SamQuigley See the edit. It does require a bit more math.